# Using akeeba backup site transfer

Tags: akeebabackup

I already have a site `www.poklo.com`. I need to work on that, so i have set up a development environment. `www.dev.poklo.com`.

Now, i have used akeeba's site transfer window, what i filled in form is:

```
The URL to your new site: http://dev.poklo.com
Host name:  ftp.poklo.com
Port:  21
Username: pokloadmin
Password: *******
FTP/SFTP Directory: public_html/dev
```

But, i have got this error:

> You have entered the connection information to the site you are
>   transfering from. Your mistake would have deleted your own site. You
>   need to enter the FTP/SFTP connection information to the site you are
>   transferring to (new site or new server). Please fix the information
>   above and retry.

How could i transfer the backup from domain to subdomain  or vice-versa using akeeba backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you're dev site is just a subdirectory on the same account so you don't need to ftp the files anywhere.  just copy the jpa file from /administrator/components/com_akeeba/backups to /dev and then use kickstart (https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) to install the dev site.